# error while installing neo4j in ubuntu

Tags: neo4j, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I am trying to install neo4j but I am getting the following

> W: GPG error: http://debian.neo4j.org/repo stable/ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 26C95CF201182252
>
> W: The repository 'http://debian.neo4j.org/repo stable/ Release' is not signed.
>
> N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
>
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
>
> Reading package lists... Done

......What to do?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to follow [the documentation](http://debian.neo4j.org/): you missed the first step,

```
wget -O - https://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then, re-run `sudo apt-get update`.